# Android beam incompatibility between 4.1.1 and 4.1.2

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I know this might sound strange but android beam is not working between 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 devices. I have two nexus'(4.1.1 and 4.1.2) and a xperia U(4.0.3). I tested the devices among themselves. Android beam works for 4.1.1 and 4.0.3 but it does not work with 4.1.2. When I bring any device near the 4.1.2 one , the touch to beam UI shows up, but the transaction never happens.I don't know if it is a hardware problem or what, but I am in a fix..Please help..